# textFieldShouldReturn ignoring variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

I have this code on my `textFieldShouldReturn` (is not in the same class as the method called):

```
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
     LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];

     if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyJoin) [loginViewController logIn];
     return (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyDone);
}
```

Everything works perfect until this point, this is the code of the "**login**" method:

```
  - (IBAction)logIn{

      NSString *username = [[self.usernameLoginField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] lowercaseString];
      NSString *password = [[self.passwordLoginField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] lowercaseString];

      NSLog(@"Username: %@ - Password: %@ ",username,password);
      //Whatever
}
```

On my `view`, I have a button that calls that method, when I use that button the `NSLog` shows what the `UITextField` contains in that moment, otherwise, If the method is called from the "**Join**" (**Return** key) from de keyboard, the `NSLog` shows null content on the variables.
What am I missing?.

Comment: The problem is that you create a new `LoginViewController` in your `textFieldShouldReturn` method instead of accessing the currently existing instance.

Comment: And how can I access the current instance?

Comment: You can get current textfield as parameter of textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField  & class instance by self. usernameLoginField or self.passwordLoginField.

Comment: I can not access to usernameLoginField using self since textFieldShouldReturn is in another class.

Comment: I am wrong, or you are clicking a login button in your LoginViewController, then you're opening a newViewController with UITextFields and then when the user clicks Join you are doing your stuff?

Comment: I think the problem is the one "rmaddy" mentioned, since I've made a few changes to see the content of the variables when I call them from my other class. As I'm instantiating a new LoginViewController those variables are set to null, and I've tried to find a way to access the currently existing instance. Gràcies!

Comment: I'll post you 2 solutions in a minute. With examples. De res.

Comment: I think the Option 4 can help you! Remember, you have the code example in GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you have 3 possible solutions:

**Option 1:** The best option IMHO.

You can use UIAlertView with UIAlertViewStyle  = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput

```
self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                            message:@"LogIn"
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", @"Join", nil];

self.alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

[self.alertView show];
```

Then with the delegate:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView == self.alertView)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [self logIn:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] andPassword:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1] text]];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }
    }
}
```

Remember to add: `UIAlertViewDelegate`

**Option 2:**

Working with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self]` and 
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

```
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.usernameLoginField)
    {
        [self.usernameLoginField resignFirstResponder];
        [self.passwordLoginField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.passwordLoginField)
    {
        [self.passwordLoginField resignFirstResponder];

        //This Identifier is in the Storyboard
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"option2Segue" sender:self];

    }

    return true;
}


 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
      [(YourViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setUsername:self.usernameLoginField.text];
      [(YourViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setPassword:self.passwordLoginField.text];
      }
```

In YourViewController.h you need:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* password;
```

Remember to add: `UITextFieldDelegate`

**Option 3**

To send back information, you should use Delegation:

In Your `firstViewController.h`:

```
#import "DelegateViewController.h"
```

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

- (void) logIn: (NSString *) username password: (NSString *) password;

In Your `firstViewController.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"option3Delegate"])
    {
        ((DelegateViewController *) segue.destinationViewController).delegate = self;
    }
}
```

In Your `delegateViewController.h`:

```
@protocol Option3Delegate <NSObject>

- (void) logIn: (NSString *) username password: (NSString *) password;

@end

@interface DelegateViewController : UIViewController
{
    id myDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<Option3Delegate> delegate;

@end
```

In Your `delegateViewController.m`:

```
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.usernameLoginField)
    {
        [self.usernameLoginField resignFirstResponder];
        [self.passwordLoginField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.passwordLoginField)
    {
        [self.passwordLoginField resignFirstResponder];

        //This Identifier is in the Storyboard

        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logIn:password:)])
        {
            [_delegate logIn:self.usernameLoginField.text password:self.passwordLoginField.text];
        }

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Remember to add: `UITextFieldDelegate`

**Option 4: With KeyboardController**

KeyboardController is a small solution to handle the Keyboard interaction inside `UITextFields`. However only handle with Next and Done Return keys. To handle the Join key you can do it in your ViewController. In the view controller where you allocate `KeyboardController`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameLoginField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordLoginField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) KeyboardController *keyboardController;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    id fields = @[self.usernameLoginField, self.passwordLoginField];
    self.keyboardController = [KeyboardController controllerWithFields:fields];

    //Important
    self.passwordLoginField.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.passwordLoginField)
    {
        [self.passwordLoginField resignFirstResponder];
        [self logIn];
    }

    return true;
}

- (IBAction)logIn
{
    NSLog(@"Username: %@ - Password: %@", self.usernameLoginField.text, self.passwordLoginField.text);
    //Whatever
}
```

You can [download an example with the 4 options here](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/loginOptions):

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and your help, although I'm confused yet. Let me try to expose it better:I'm using a drop-in solution for managing the keyboard controller, the "textFieldShouldReturn" method is implemented in the "KeyboardController.m" with the code posted above, and the method "login" is in "LoginViewController.m". To call "login" from "KeyboardController.m" I'm instantiating that class, which sets the username and password variables to null since "self.usernameLoginField.text" seems that can't be accessed, but if I replace it with @"Hi" NSLog shows Hi, so there's the prob

Comment: You should try to adapt one of the 3 options into your project. No doubt,  you error line is: `LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];`. If you are working with storyboards you do not need to instantiate LoginVC. You can access it through the segue.

Comment: This is your sequence, right? 1. LoginVC 2. Alloc and show KeyboardController 3 Instantiate again LoginVC 4 Print null.

Comment: I was looking to use the second one using the segue, but how could I use a segue if "KeyboardController" is not a ViewController, I mean, in your solution you are setting the variables through the segue between two views, but what I'm trying to do is to set those variables from "KeyboardController" in "LoginViewcontroller"

Comment: Yes it is, this is the solution I'm using in case it helps https://github.com/michalkonturek/KeyboardController

Comment: Your KeyboardController is just an object. Like a button or a TExtField or a LAbel. So you are allocating it inside a ViewController. Which one? Inside LoginViewCOntroller?

Comment: In "LoginViewController" there's a _setupFieldsMethod with this line "    self.keyboardController = [KeyboardController controllerWithFields:fields];" in "KeyboardController" that instance allocates the object and initializes it with an array of fields previously set.

Comment: So you don't need to allocate again LoginViewController, because your self is LoginViewController. You can: `if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyJoin) [self logIn];`

Comment: No visible @interface for 'KeyboardController' declares the selector 'logIn'; Apparently I can't, don't worry, I'll try to find out a solution and as soon as I find it I'll post it here. Thank you for all your help and time, appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57744/discussion-between-gabriel-massana-and-idec).